# UICollectionView rotation animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have two different UIViewControllers, and both of them have UiCollectionView.
Problems appears when I try rotate iPad.
Next I have in portrait position

[image]

When I rotate to landscape I reload my collectionView, so in lanscape mode I need have 3 columns

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

In first viewController all good, and when collectionView begin rotate controller still have 3 columns

[image]

But when I try do it in another controller, I get bad situation

[image]

It is looks like in one moment two collectionView in my view, and then one of them is disappearing.

I use standart UICollectionViewFlowLayout and have same methods for buils layout

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invoking the view..

- (void)invalidateLayout

You can call this method at any time to update the layout information. This method invalidates the layout of the collection view itself and returns right away. Thus, you can call this method multiple times from the same block of code without triggering multiple layout updates. The actual layout update occurs during the next view layout update cycle.

Comment: I tried early '[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];' but I had same results

Comment: Strange!

shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:
Asks the layout object if the new bounds require a layout update.

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds

Apparently this is **REQUIRED** with CollectionViews are you calling this?

Answer (score -1):

Have you also tried this?

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
  }

Comment: Yes, I now use it, but it's not solution, because it is disappear on some moment, when rotating in action, but I need rotate without disappearong of collectionView

Answer (score -2):

I think I have solution, try this which understands when animating the rotation;

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(    NSTimeInterval)duration {

  [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
  }